# 5 days abandoned

Tags: riddle, word

> **6 days ago** I was left on a deserted island.
> **5 days ago** I had some hope so I was fine.
> **4 days ago** I outlined SOS on the ground.
> **3 days ago** I felt defeated and depressed.
> **2 days ago** I got saved by a branded ship.

Find the hidden word in the story.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe...

> Strand ?
>  Strand (6) is to leave alone on an island
>  Stand (5) is to rise up with hope
>  Sand (4) is what you drew SOS in
>  Sad (3) is defeated and depressed
>  Ad (2) is a branding that was on the branded ship

Glad you were rescued from that beach!

> (Strand is German for beach incidentally)

Comment: It can mean that in English too.